# Added Gnome DE to my ubuntu server 17.04 install, now display is not correct resolution?

Tags: gnome, 17.04

output of `lspci | grep VGA` shows me this:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

but i only have 800x600 listed in the display options (unknown display).

I can't figure out if I need to uninstall the driver for the video card or what, or where even to do that.

Comment: Is this a server? As far as I know xeons (minus a select few new ones) don't have graphics processors integrated. Depending on which 1200 series it is, it might have it. If it is a server it's possible 800x600 is it's only capable output. Older Dells use the idrac6 controller for example. It would be helpful to know what the hardware is.

Comment: just tell me the command and ill show you the output.  it had windows 7 on it, back in the day.